# Is there a command that will find all usage of a referenced component?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have some references in a solution that I am not sure about. I can always remove the reference and build to see what breaks. Is there a command or maybe an extension that will analyze the reference and find all of the code that relies on it?

Comment: Something like [this ReShaper feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Remove_Unused_References.html)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. You get bonus points if you can find a free tool :-)

Comment: ReSharper 30-day trial? 